# touch control to move cube (in an array that generates them) left and right

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am moving an object that consists of two cubes: left and right. These cubes are randomly generated on the y-axis upwards.

I am able to move them left and right with no problem, however, when I move one of the cubes left or right they all move.

How am I able to only move one of the cubes when touched only left or right rather than all of them? Here is my code below:

Generate cubes code:

```
public Transform block;
public Transform player;
private float objectSpawnedTo = 5.0f;
public static float distanceBetweenObjects = 5.0f;
private float nextCheck = 0.0f;
private ArrayList objects = new ArrayList();
void Start () {
    maintenance(0.0f);
}


void Update () {
    float playerX = player.position.y;
    if(playerX > nextCheck)
    {
        maintenance(playerX);
    }
}

private void maintenance(float playerX)
{
    nextCheck = playerX + 30;
    for (int i = objects.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        Transform blck = (Transform)objects[i];
        if(blck.position.y < (transform.position.y - 30))
        {
            Destroy(blck.gameObject);
            objects.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    spawnObjects(5);
}

private void spawnObjects(int howMany)
{
    float spawnX = objectSpawnedTo;
    for(int i = 0; i<howMany; i++)
    {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(-3.5f,spawnX, 0);
        //float firstRandom = Random.Range(-6.0f, 1.0f);
        Transform blck = (Transform)Instantiate(block, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        //blck.localScale+=new Vector3(firstRandom*2,0,0);
        objects.Add(blck);
        //pos = new Vector3(0,spawnX, 0);
        //blck = (Transform)Instantiate(block, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        //blck.localScale +=new Vector3((8.6f-firstRandom)*2,0,0);
        //objects.Add(blck);
        spawnX = spawnX + distanceBetweenObjects;
    }
    objectSpawnedTo = spawnX;
}

}
```

Cube-control code:

```
public float speed = 5;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

void Update() {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
        // Get movement of the finger since last frame
        Vector3 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

        // Move object across XY plane
        transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, 0);


        Vector3 boundaryVector = transform.position;   
        boundaryVector.x = Mathf.Clamp (boundaryVector.x, -5.5f, -2.8f);
        transform.position = boundaryVector;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your cube-control code has no condition in it about which cube is selected : you simply wait for `Input.touchCount` to be > 0 and then move the cube. So all the cube having this script will move.

I think what you need to do is a raycast to check which cube has been "touched" and then only move it if raycast is successful :

```
[SerializeField]
private float speed = 0.5f;

private int MAX_TOUCH_COUNT = 5;
private bool[] touched;

protected void Start()
{
    touched = new bool[MAX_TOUCH_COUNT];
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < (Input.touchCount <= MAX_TOUCH_COUNT ? Input.touchCount : MAX_TOUCH_COUNT); i++)
        {
            if(touched[i] && Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                touched[i] = false;
            }
            else if (!touched[i] && Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
                RaycastHit hitInfo;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
                {
                    if (hitInfo.transform.GetComponentInChildren<*YOUR_CUBE_CONTROL_CLASS_NAME*>() == this)
                    {
                        touched[i] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (touched[i] && Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                // Get movement of the finger since last frame
                Vector3 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(i).deltaPosition;

                // Move object across XY plane
                transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, 0);

                Vector3 boundaryVector = transform.position;   
                boundaryVector.x = Mathf.Clamp (boundaryVector.x, -5.5f, -2.8f);
                transform.position = boundaryVector;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            touched  = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help,

Comment: thanks for the comment, ive used this code but im getting errors related to raycast? how can i solve this. also what do i have to do to work with the rest of touches instead of the first one. im new to unity so if you could point me in the right direction i would appreciate it

Comment: I fixed the provided code errors (mainly due to the fact I wrote it here and didn't tested it) and tested it: it works fine. Make sure you're testing it on a touch device: it won't work with the mouse clicks since `Input.GetTouch()` is used. About making it work with the rest of touches, I simply converted the `touched` bool logic to an array of bool.

Comment: yes, its working. now with this i can only move the cubes left and right when i select the main cube which is the parent of the gameobject right, how can i move the gameobject left and right but when i touch the child of the gameobject. im guessing you would have to use GetComponentsInChildren?

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to achieve and how your scene hierarchy is organized : could you post a screen of it and maybe a graphic explanation of your goal ?